# Make CSS popup dissapeer when blanket is clicked (Example: Facebook Photo's)

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup

i have a css popup div that when it loads through the onClick it also brings up a blanket of transparency kind of like how Facebook does when you look at photos

How do i get that popup div to close when i click on the blanket?

Heres the code

'

```
<center><div id="blanket" style="display:none;">
</div>

<table width="1000" border="0">    
  <tr>

 <td>  
<div id="mainAdminCP">

<div class="editRecipe" >
<a href="#" onclick="popup('popUpAdminEditRecipe');return false;"><h2>Edit Recipe</h2></a> 
</div>
<div id="popUpAdminEditRecipe" style="display:none;" align="center"> 
<br />
<br />
<form id="editRecipe">
<fieldset id="inputs">
    <input id="username" type="text" placeholder="Please insert the name of the recipe" autofocus required>   
    <br />
    <br />
    <input id="add" type="text" placeholder="Recipe Name" required>
    <input id="add" type="text" placeholder="Recipe Ingredients" required>
    <input id="add" type="text" placeholder="Recipe Instructions" required>
    <input id="add" type="text" placeholder="Recipe Image" required>
</fieldset>
<fieldset id="actions">
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Save Changes">
    <input type="submit" id="submit" onClick="popup('popUpAdminEditRecipe')" value="Close">
</fieldset>
</form>
</div>   

<div class="editCoins"> 
<a href="#" onclick="popup('popUpAdminEditCoins');return false;"><h2>Edit Coins</h2></a> 
</div>
<div id="popUpAdminEditCoins" style="display:none;" align="center"> 
<br />
<br />
<form id="login">
<fieldset id="inputs">
    <input id="username" type="text" placeholder="Please insert the Username of the User" autofocus required>   
    <input id="add" type="text" placeholder="Add Coins" required>
    <input id="add" type="text" placeholder="Subtract Coins" required>
</fieldset>
<fieldset id="actions">
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
    <input type="submit" id="submit" onClick="popup('popUpAdminEditCoins')" value="Close">
</fieldset>
```

'

And heres the link to the page itself to get a clear example of what im looking for.

http://teknologenie.com/fruitforest/admincp.php

Ive tried placing the 
    `<a href="#" onClick="popup('popUpAdminEditUser')" > </a>` 
Within the blanket div, and nothing. Just kind of screws everything up.

**Edit:** 
Also if you visit the link, and click the text, the whole div doesnt get directly in the middle of the screen and i need it to be. Any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of putting an link inside the blanket div, pup an onclick function on the blanket div itself:

```
<div id="blanket" onclick="closePopup()" style="height: 681px; display: block;"></div>
```

The function closePopup should then set display none to the popup and the blanket:

```
function closePopup() { 
    document.getElementById('blanket').style.display = 'none';               
    document.getElementById('popUpAdminEditCoins').style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: How would i do this for all the different 'popUpAdminEditCoins and popUpAdminEditUsers... etc etc... would i do it like so?

    

`function closePopup() { 
    document.getElementById('blanket').style.display = 'none';               
    document.getElementById('popUpAdminEditCoins, popUpAdminEditUsers, popUpAdminEditTree, etc, etc').style.display = 'none';
}`

Comment: Heres what i had to use

`function closePopup() { 
    document.getElementById('blanket').style.display = 'none';             
    document.getElementById('popUpAdminEditCoins').style.display = 'none';
 document.getElementById('popUpAdminEditUser').style.display = 'none';
 document.getElementById('popUpAdminEditTree').style.display = 'none';
 document.getElementById('popUpAdminEditRecipe').style.display = 'none';
}`

Also i had to take the the `style="height: 681px;` it was causing the blanket to load on the start of the page.

Comment: I am noticing though, that its a little buggy, when i click a popup for the FIRST time it doesnt load the blanket, but yet after i close the popup out and click it or another one again its fine... Any thoughts?

Comment: I've written a full example for you below, it shouldn't be difficult to apply to your case.

Comment: I can't seem to replicate that problem. The blanket loads the first time I click the links after loading the page.

Comment: I havnt uploaded the new work yet if your using my link. I will upload now.

Answer (score 1):

I've written you an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/KXK6E/2/

You'd be much better off binding events within the javascript rather than within the HTML.

```
document.getElementById("blanket").onclick = function(e){
    document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "none";
    e.target.style.display = "none";
};

document.getElementById("trigger").onclick = function(){ 
    document.getElementById("blanket").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "block";
}
```

​

Comment: Im still not getting the popup to center dead on in the middle, other then that everything works great.